# Using Branch links to deeplink to unpublished app

Tags: branch.io

I'm working as a web developer for a start-up that has a andriod app prototype. I'm not an app developer ( still learning) so I'm a little unsure how to approach this.

I wanted to deeplink the app to the webpage. I came across this solution called Branch.io . It looks like exactly what we need but I'm not sure how to link it with an unpublished app. Maybe I'm missing something. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The Branch service actually doesn't depend on the App or Play Store at all. The link will first try to open up the app, but fallback to the store pages if not installed. You can override this fallback to any website, and the links will still function as usual.

To test an app not in the Play Store, first choose 'Custom URL' in the Link Settings dashboard, and fill in the page you'd like to send users when the app is not installed. It's common for people to send users to either their home page or TestFlight app.

[image]

Then, to test the deep linking through install and download tracking, just do the following:

1. Create a Branch link
2. Click it on your phone or on simulator and wait to be redirected
3. Run the app from Android Studio/Eclipse

Here are some more [testing considerations](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/testing_your_integration/android/). Happy linking.

Comment: What would be the custom link for an app that is in TestFlight ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can set it to anything while it's in TestFlight (i.e. https://google.com, https://branch.io, etc). We just match the click of the Branch link to the app session, no matter if the app is downloaded from the store, loaded from Xcode or downloaded from TestFlight.